# Grub prompt after every restart from ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I dual booted my laptop yesterday. It has 256 gb SSD and 1 Tb HDD. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in that 1 Tb HDD and installed grub bootloader in SSD.
When I reboot from Windows everything works fine. But after I reboot from Ubuntu, it shows the grub prompt. Everytime I need to type exit to bring back the grub loader.

I have tried boot-repair but nothing changed and this is the link generated.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vSFmbqy5YB/

Please help me with this problem and I am new to linux.

Thanks in advance...

[This is what I get when I reboot from ubuntu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjgC5.jpg)

Comment: As it says, did you try turning UEFI Secure Boot off? What brand/model system? Have you updated UEFI and updated NVMe firmware?

Comment: Yes I did turned off UEFI secure boot. My laptop model is asus ROG strix g531gt. Yes my Firmwares were up to date.

Comment: Other ROG, often issues common by brand, not specific model: Asus RROG Strix G17 Intel Core i7-10750H Nvidia
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279496/hard-time-installing-ubuntu-20-04-as-dual-boot-on-asus-rox-strix-g17
Asus ROG Zephyrus GA502 Ryzen 7 3750H + Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti Set up Guide
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2440670