# Can't put AHCI mode on my laptop working with intel RST, so, how can I Install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, intel, ahci, rst

I have ASUS ROG Zephyrus DUO 15 Laptop and due to its 10th generation intel cpu and 2 1TB nvme ssd I can't put the AHCI mode in Bios. Is it possible to install Ubuntu with intel RST mode enabled?

Comment: It is possible to install Ubuntu in RST mode. But installing in dual boot with Windows is not always possible or easy.

Comment: The Asus BIOS is sometimes a little "special". You will first need to disable "Secure Boot" in the BIOS, which will break BitLocker in Windows. Only after "Secure Boot" is disabled will you find the option for ACPI in the SATA device menu (not anywhere near the NVMe settings). Once set, it should be possible to see the storage device(s) from the Ubuntu installation media.

Comment: Possibly similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279496/hard-time-installing-ubuntu-20-04-as-dual-boot-on-asus-rog-strix-g17

Comment: @Pilot6 I'd appreciate if you could provide instructions on how to do dual boot with Windows. Thx!

Comment: There is no such instruction.

Comment: On my current laptop I initially had Ubuntu installed alongside Windows 10 with iRST. Foolishly I switched to AHCI and was unable to switch back. I had notes on the setup but had tossed them out.