# Unable to install/boot Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb, freeze, usb-installation

I've been trying to boot from a USB ISO of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

I'm on a ROG G20CB with an NVIDIA 1080

I also already have windows 10 installed on the PC.

I followed the steps to flash it onto a USB and successfully change my boot option over to the USB.

However, whenever I go to "try Ubuntu without installing" it just freezes.

If I try to install it just has a spinning loading mouse icon and nothing happens.

I tried to use safe graphics mode - no dice

I tried to go back and disable fast boot, disable secure boot - no dice

I tried to enter no nomodeset - still freezes

I tried to enter nouveau.modeset=0 - still freezes

Does anyone have any idea how I can get it to finally load? I would greatly appreciate any support!

Comment: have you tried the usb on an other pc?

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have any other PC’s to try it out on :/

Comment: hey did you checked the if secure boot is enabled or disabled in bios or try other distro like pop! os since it has drivers for nvidia

Comment: I did make sure that the secure boot is disabled but that didn’t seem to help either. I guess I will have to check into Pop! OS

Comment: Ubuntu has drivers for nVidia. Safe Boot uses nomodeset for lower quality until you install with optional drivers so nVidia driver also installed. Have you updated UEFI to latest available. And if NVMe drive updated its firmware? Is drive in RAID or AHCI mode? May be similar: Asus ROG Strix G17 Intel Core i7-10750H Nvidia
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279496/hard-time-installing-ubuntu-20-04-as-dual-boot-on-asus-rox-strix-g17 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/694453/new-laptop-skylake-cannot-boot-xubuntu-even-with-boot-parameters

Comment: I will try to update my bios and see if that works at all. I got Linux Mint to boot up at least. But, even that is eventually running into errors.

Comment: by the way make sure you are downloading nvidia one