# Ubuntu Install/Boot black screen or Stuck

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04, 23.10, amd-processor

The problem occurs when trying to install ubuntu 22.04 LTS or 23.10.

If you run try or install without `nomodeset`, then in almost all cases the screen goes off and nothing happens (a couple of times I managed to get to launch, but almost immediately the system stuck dead).

I tried to run it with `nomodeset`. It was possible to get to the launch, but often the system stuck dead after a question about wi-fi.

It was installed once, but the same problems occurred at startup: without `nomodeset`, the screen is black, with `nomodeset`, it stuck deadly after a couple of minutes after startup.

Notebook ASUS ROG STRIX SCAR 15 (2021).

AMD Ryzen™ 9 5900HX
NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 3070 Laptop GPU

Comment: I successfully installed and launched ubuntu on 21.04.
But I still wonder why it didn't work with 22.04 and 23.10.

Comment: Have you updated firmware UEFI & SSD? Are you using Safe Boot which I think is just nomodeset) and choosing the install optional restricted drivers? Asus ROG Strix G17 Intel Core i7-10750H Nvidia
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279496/hard-time-installing-ubuntu-20-04-as-dual-boot-on-asus-rox-strix-g17
Asus ROG Zephyrus GA502 Ryzen 7 3750H + Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti Set up Guide
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2440670  Hopefully new enough not to have Optane: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a bit.

The problem was not with the ubuntu versions. As I found out, when the laptop is running on battery power, everything is fine, when I connect the charging, the system freezes after a few minutes.

Also, if you run ubuntu without charging, then everything works fine. If with charging connected, then the screen is black and stuck.

So I'll deal with it.